# How to sort a table by mean after using groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that was created with a groupby function, and I want to sort it from highest mean to lowest mean. However, I keep getting the error message: "'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sort_values'" or sometimes "bool object is not callable".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("Listings.csv")

df2 = df[df['city'].str.contains("Cape Town")] 
df2_by_neighbourhood = df2.groupby('neighbourhood')
df2_by_neighbourhood.describe()

df2_by_neighbourhood.sort_values(['mean'], ascending=False)
```

When I get rid of the last line, the table comes out perfectly, but the mean isn't from highest to lowest. It gives me this:

| neighbourhood | count | mean | std | min | 25% | 50% | 75% | price max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ward 1 | 207 | 1181 | 1422 | 210.0 | 524.0 | 750.0 | 1145 | 10000 |

(etc., 93 rows in total)

The data BEFORE using groupby looks like this:

| neighbourhood | city | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ward 115 | Cape Town | 700 |

[19086 rows x 3 columns]

I can't sort the table before using the groupby function, because groupby is how I'm getting the mean values.

Comment: You mentioned `the table comes out perfectly, but **the mean** isn't from highest to lowest.`  So, what's the column name of the `mean` or where is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df2_by_neighbourhood['mean'].shift(0).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

to get the `mean` column as a series, in descending order.

If you want to show the whole dataframe `df2_by_neighbourhood` (instead of just the `mean` column) in descending order of values of column `mean`, you can use:

```
df2_by_neighbourhood.loc[df2_by_neighbourhood['mean'].shift(0).argsort().sort_values(ascending=False)]
```

### Edit

As seen from your newly released sample data, you can take the `mean` of column `price` as follows:

```
df2_by_neighbourhood['price'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Taking your data sample and add some rows, you can see the results as follows:

```
data = {'neighbourhood': ['Ward 115', 'Ward 115', 'Ward 226', 'Ward 226'],
 'city': ['Cape Town', 'Cape Town', 'Cape Town', 'Cape Town'],
 'price': [700, 900, 1000, 1200]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df2)

  neighbourhood       city  price
0      Ward 115  Cape Town    700
1      Ward 115  Cape Town    900
2      Ward 226  Cape Town   1000
3      Ward 226  Cape Town   1200
```

Run the codes:

```
df2_by_neighbourhood = df2.groupby('neighbourhood')
df2_by_neighbourhood['price'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
neighbourhood
Ward 226    1100
Ward 115     800
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

Here, the mean values of `price` for 2 groups are sorted in descending order.

Comment: This gives me another error: "'Column not found: mean'"

Comment: @atrimi  I seen from your code you tried to access a column name of `mean`.  That's why I thought your data should have that column.  Also you mentioned you seen the mean but not in correct ordering.  To allow us help you better, please post some sample data.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've edited the post with some of the data. I'm not sure why the "mean" column can't be found, that is the name of it.

Comment: @atrimi  The mean that you seen is the output of `.describe()` which is the standard statistics provided by Pandas.  It is not a real data inside your dataframe.  So, you cannot sort it.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @atrimi  I am editing to show you how you can really make your `mean` for the `price` column within group.  Stay tuned.

Comment: @atrimi  See my edit above showing you the `mean` values of `price` for 2 groups sorted in descending order.